# Bot de Telegram desde C# a grupo Privado de Telegram

Tags: c#, telegram, bot

cree un Bot en Telegram por medio de la herramienta que ofrece Telegram botfather telegram, luego cree un grupo en telegram donde coloque al BOT como administrador, cuando envio el mensaje desde mi programa en C# por medio de Bot con el grupo Public, funciona el mensaje es enviado al grupo de Telegram, pero cuando pero cuando coloco el grupo en privado private, me genera una exepcion.

que me falta, que debo hacer?

Gracias por el apoyo

```
    _botClient =
        new TelegramBotClient("XXXXXXXXX:ZZZZZZ-NtqXXXXDOMOeDcGYFXoTJsl34ax2Y");
   await _botClient.SendTextMessageAsync("@enclouserpba", "text message");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que poner todo el código fuente para poder reproducir tu escenario, caso contrario, estamos a ciegas y así, las chances de conseguir respuesta, son muy bajas. Saludos.